# Do they have a HTML/XAML like concept in the Flash/Flex world?

Tags: flash, apache-flex

In Silverlight graphic artists are expected to know XAML. With webstites it is HTML/CSS. What do the graphic artists using Flash/Flex use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really agree with you on the "are expected to know" part.  There is really no authority to decide what's expected of graphic artists, other than being good graphic artists.

But since Flash comes with extensive graphics functionality, it is probably most important for graphic artists working in a Flash/Flex-related production process to know how to use these. Also, they should be instructed on how to prepare bitmap or video content for embedding in Flash, and to have some idea of the object model used in Flash, so they are able to create and manage library items in a way that can be effectively used and/or extended by ActionScript programmers.

Apart from that, for anyone working with more than "just" graphics, i.e. graphic artists who do active programming on UI components in Flash/Flex, it is handy to know:

- MXML: The Flex xml dialect used to create views.
- HTML: Flash allows for a limited number of HTML tags (a, b, p, font, span, br, img, i, ul, li, u, plus the generic "textformat") when using styled text.
- CSS: Flash can use CSS to style text.  As with HTML, this is not a complete implementation, but restricted to font and character formats
- Also, the Flash player is often embedded in an HTML page - for this, some JavaScript and whatever other languages used on the web server will also come in handy.

It is also good to have a firm knowledge of XML and JSON when working with ActionScript, but on the graphics end of the production process, these will probably not be as important.

Comment: +1.  However, I'd add FXG to your list of things "Graphic Atists" might want to know, with MXML Graphics a secondary skill.  Some form of Adobe design tool (Illustrator, Photoshop, or Fireworks) that integrates with FXG and probably Flash Catalyst for preparing designs for Flex Programmers.

Comment: There is no authority that says what a programmer is supposed to know either, but I wouldn't hire one who didn't know what an array it. Likewise I wouldn't hire a graphic artist on a Silverlight project who didn't know XAML.

Comment: @Jonathan: That's not really the same thing.  A programmer who doesn't know what an array is clearly lacks basic skills related to *programming*.  I wouldn't hire a graphic artist who doesn't know how to hold a pen, either.  But depending on the structure of your team, it is quite conceivable that you could have a talented graphic artist working only with vector graphics and bitmaps, and have someone else take care of translating those into assets for Flash or Silverlight programming.